# Let installer create an auto-run shortcut on windows startup for only one user

Tags: windows, nsis

I have a NSIS installer that installs my application and it creates a shortcut in the Startup folder (Which allows my application to start-up when Windows starts up.

```
;Create Auto Startup Shortcut
CreateShortCut "$SMSTARTUP\my_app.lnk" "$INSTDIR\Bin\my_app.exe"
```

However, now my application autostarts for all users who log into the machine. I only want it to auto-run for the user who installed the application.

Comment: Can you clarify if you are using MultiUser.nsh?

Answer (score 0):

NSIS confusingly calls the "Current User" option [MultiUser](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/MultiUser/Readme.html), as in "MultiUser.nsh". Anyway, this script (when run with `MULTIUSER_EXECUTIONLEVEL=Standard`) will allow you to install for the current user only.

Comment: MultiUser allows you to choose between single/current user and all users.

Comment: @Anders: Yes, and that is the choice you need. By default it's an all-user install.

Comment: You don't need MultiUser to perform a single user installation, you only need it if you want the ability to choose the install type.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of installation scenarios

1. Install something only for the current user.
2. Install something for every user on the machine.

In NSIS you perform the current/single user mode by

- Adding `RequestExecutionLevel user` to the script.
- Only writing to the HKCU part of the registry.
- Installing the application to $LocalAppData\Programs.

And the machine/shared/all users mode by

- Adding `RequestExecutionLevel admin` and `SetShellVarContext all` to the script.
- Only writing to the HKLM/HKCR parts of the registry.
- Installing the application to $ProgramFiles.
- **Not** writing to HKCU nor any parts of a users profile.

In NSIS some of the path constants like $SMPrograms are affected by the `SetShellVarContext` instruction, it can be used to toggle between the user and shared/machine folder paths. You should however always match it to the type of installation you are doing because UAC can cause installers to run as "the wrong user" and non-admin users don't have write access to the shared folders.

MultiUser.nsh attempts to give you a way to choose the mode at run-time but you have to be careful because you don't want to perform actions for a single user when performing a shared installation.

If you are installing for all users then the installer cannot set up per-user startup shortcuts, it must be done by your application when the user executes it.

If you don't care about the possibility of running as the wrong user because of UAC you can change to the users folder constants:

```
SetShellVarContext user ; Force per-user folder constants
CreateShortcut "$SMSTARTUP\my_app.lnk" "$INSTDIR\Bin\my_app.exe"
```